# How to Save as png with ChartJSRadar in R?

Tags: r, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm trying to save my plot with resolution of 300 for publication purposes. The usual methods to save plots with png device isn't working and saves a blank png. Is there something else I can try, or a different package that does something similar?

```
library(radarchart)
data<-data.frame(Field=c("Age","Sex","Submission"), y=sample(1:100,3), x=sample(1:100,3))
path<-"C:\\Desktop\\R\\"
png(file=paste0(path,"Radar",".png"), width=500, height=500, res=300)
plot<-chartJSRadar(scores=data,  labelSize= 10, main="Completeness Radar", maxScale = 100)
print(plot)
dev.off()
```

I've also tried:

```
png(file=paste0(path,"Radar",".png"), width=500, height=500, res=300)
chartJSRadar(scores=data,  labelSize= 10, main="Completeness Radar", maxScale = 100)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(radarchart)
library(webshot)
library(htmlwidgets)

dat <- data.frame(
  Field = c("Age","Sex","Submission"), 
  y = sample(1:100,3), 
  x = sample(1:100,3)
)

plt <- chartJSRadar(
  scores = dat,
  labelSize= 10, 
  main="Completeness Radar", 
  maxScale = 100
)

saveWidget(plt, "plt.html")

webshot("plt.html")

magick::image_read("webshot.png")
```

[image]

- radar charts are very difficult for folks to grok
- `data` and `plot` are suberbad variable names
- whitespace is your bff
- `webshot` can limit target area
- various `magick` ƒ()s can crop target area
- consider using http://www.ggplot2-exts.org/ggradar.html

Comment: Thanks for this- just quickly threw together a reproducible example.  Does this allow for specifying a specific resolution though?